# PostgreSQL notifications aren't working

Tags: postgresql, event-notification

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL notifications but they are not working for me.

## Docker-Compose

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

secrets:
  db_root:
    file: ./db/.secrets/.psql_name_admin
  db_pwd:
    file: ./db/.secrets/.psql_pwd_admin
  db_dbname:
    file: ./db/.secrets/.psql_name_db

services: 
  db:
    build: 
      context: ./db
    restart: unless-stopped
    secrets:
      - db_root
      - db_pwd
      - db_dbname
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB_FILE=/run/secrets/db_dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/db_root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_pwd
    ports: 
      - 5442:5432
    volumes: 
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

### ./db/Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest
COPY init/*.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

### ./db/init/0_blogpost.sql

```
CREATE TYPE BLOGPOST_ENUM AS ENUM ('Technical', 'Agile');

CREATE TABLE writer (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    name TEXT NOT NULL ,
    surname TEXT NOT NULL ,
    nick TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE blog_post (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    title TEXT NOT NULL ,
    content TEXT NOT NULL ,
    blogpost_type BLOGPOST_ENUM NOT NULL ,
    writer_id SERIAL REFERENCES writer(id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blogpost_added_subscription()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify(
        'blogpost_added' ,
--      json_build_object(
--          'event' , 'newBlogpostAdded' ,
--          'subject' , new.id
--      )::text
    new.id::text
    );

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER notifiy_after_blogpost_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON blog_post
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE blogpost_added_subscription()
;

INSERT INTO writer (name, surname) VALUES ('Emanuel', 'Vollmer');

INSERT INTO blog_post (title, content, blogpost_type, writer_id)
VALUES (
 'Graphql',
 'Graphql is a query language...',
 'Technical',
 (SELECT id FROM writer WHERE name = 'Emanuel')
);

INSERT INTO blog_post (title, content, blogpost_type, writer_id)
VALUES (
 'Flutter',
 'Flutter is a framework for Dart...',
 'Technical',
 (SELECT id FROM writer WHERE name = 'Emanuel')
);
```

## Working with pgcli

I opened two sessions with

```
$ pgcli -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5442 -U sysmanager -d demo_db
```

On session 1 I run

```
sysmanager@0:demo_db> listen blogpost_added;
LISTEN
Time: 0.001s
```

On session 2 I run

```
sysmanager@0:demo_db> INSERT INTO blog_post (title, content, blogpost_type, writer_id)
 VALUES (
  'PostgreSQL Notifiers',
  'PostgreSQL is a powerful, open source object-relational database system...',
  'Technical',
  (SELECT id FROM writer WHERE name = 'Emanuel')
 );
INSERT 0 1
Time: 0.021s
```

But I'm not receiving any notifications on Session 1, Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `pgcli` does not display notifications.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli/pull/1385) about this feature.

The solution is to use `psql` instead.

Note that notifications are not displayed in psql immediately as they're produced by the server, but when there are interactions with the database. When psql is waiting for user input, it's not waken up by incoming notifications.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> Whenever a command is executed, psql also polls for asynchronous
> notification events generated by LISTEN and
> NOTIFY.

Comment: Same result. I've run `docker-compose exec db bash` then `psql -U sysmanager -d demo_db` for two sessions but no notifications.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα: I assume it's because the psql session that listens doesn't send any query. I've updated the answer to mention that it doesn't display notifications in that case.

Comment: This is so weird, I'm trying to reproduce what was done in this [video](https://youtu.be/UIVMGMD6HT0?t=228) with the same docker-compose file, but no notifications. I think something is missing.